# function overloading in C#

Tags: c#-3.0

in c++ , compiler used name mangaling is to differntiate the function that are overloaded.In C# how the function overloading is handled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature of the method is used (types and numbers of parameters) to distinguish the different overloads.

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691336%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691131%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) (rather dated, but still pretty accurate) articles on MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

Before invoking the method, the compiler automatically finds out the best overloaded method matching the list of arguments type.